# What would cause a table with 80,000 records to use 145GB of space?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, storage

I have a table that gets inserted and deleted from every day.  On average the record count is 80,000.  Roughly 20 fields, 10 of which are VARCHAR(4000) however most of the records have those fields empty.  1 NC Index account for 8MB.

The job that loads this table runs as expected with no performance issues.

This table has been slowly growing 1GB a day with MINIMAL record count increase(sometimes decrease).  I cant seem to pin point what would cause this.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the job loading the table using a bulk insert method? If so, how many rows per batch?

Comment: Not sure what the job is using, its BizTalk,  but from what I was told from the dev it sounds like its loading in a complete new set of data and then removing duplicates to keep the DIFF of the set....so attempting to house incremental data.  It runs dozens of times through out the day.  

Truncating and reloading the table brought the size down to 13MB.  I suspect SQL has allocated too much space per record due to the 10 huge fields?

Comment: I doubt the declared varchar max length is the problem. The reason I asked about batch size is that full 64K extents are allocated by default with each bulk insert batch when trace flag 1118 is enabled (default behavior in SQL 2016 and later). This can quickly add up to a lot of unused space with batches containing a few records. Exec sp_spaceused 'YourTable' to see if you have large unused space and, if so, check to see if the trace flag is on.

Comment: Ahh I see, thats interesting that you mention that because just after replying to your last comment I had noticed 4 times unused space for that table.  I will check the trace flag.  I think you are right.

Comment: Does it have a clustered index? If not, it’s a heap and it won’t clean up the space caused by deletes.

Comment: @SQLcommando, Rob's comment could be a cause depending on your deletes. I seldom used heaps and didn't think of that.

Comment: No it does not have a clustered index!  I didnt know that would happen with heaps regarding deletes.  There are tons of deletes going on through out the day.  I think itts one of these two causes.  Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: [DELETE Operation in SQL Server HEAPs](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/delete-operation-sql-server-heaps/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a clustered index so that your table is not a heap. When a row is deleted from a heap, the space will not be reused. Even empty pages don’t get cleared up. This problem won’t happen if your table is a clustered index.